# How to use NDSolve to track equilibrium?

Tags: numerics, numerical-integration, differential-equations

I am looking for an extension of `NDSolve` where integration runs until certain variables are settled at an equilibrium. Now I have a working solution in my sleeves but I would rather not show it yet, as I want answers to be unbiased and original, since I'm not convinced that my solution is optimal at all.

Consider the following putative example (note that `EquilibriumNDSolve` is an undefined hypothetical function):

```
eqns = {
   Derivative[1][a][t] == -a[t] - 0.2` a[t]^2 + 2.1` b[t],
   Derivative[1][b][t] == a[t] + 0.1` a[t]^2 - 1.1` b[t],
   a[0] == 0.5`,
   b[0] == 0.5`
   };

steps = {};

sol = EquilibriumNDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1000}, a + b, 
   EquilibriumThreshold -> 10^-5, 
   EquilibriumStepMonitor :> AppendTo[steps, t]
   ];
```

This reads as: "numerically solve *eqns* for *a* and *b* variables while *t* goes from 0, until (*a* + *b*) is settled at an equilibrium. If no equilibrium is reached until *t* = 1000", terminate. The solution should be a set of `{y.i -> InterpolatingFunction[...]}` (just like in case of `NDSolve`), and the result should be something like this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, Last[steps]}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], ImageSize -> 400, 
 GridLines -> {steps, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> {Dashed, GrayLevel[.7]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Vertical gridlines indicate positions where an equilibrium test was performed. The syntax and usage should vaguely work like this:

> `EquilibriumNDSolve[eqns, {y1, y2, ...}, {t, t0, tmax},
>   z}]` numerically solves the differential equation system *eqns* for
>   all variables $y_i$, with independent variable *t* running from $t_0$ to
>   a maximum of $t_{max}$. Iteration stops when variable *z* settles at an
>   equilibrium or no equilibrium was found in the given range of *t*.
>   Variable *z* can be a single variable, a list of variables, or any
>   sensible combination of them, e.g. $a+b$.

`EquilibriumThreshold` should define a threshold value above which no equilibrium is registered. `EquilibriumStepMonitor` should work like `StepMonitor`: each time an equilibrium-test is performed, the *rhs* of `EquilibriumStepMonitor :> func` is evaluated as well.

Comment: I'm curious to see what solution you have up your sleeve :)

Comment: @JxB: I had the very same solution everyone posted below, so no unexpected solutions have pop up. Mine has a fine tuned sampling method and some necessary additions to be able to package the function. If someone is interested, I can post the function in its entirety.

Comment: I would be very interested in that, @IstvánZachar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This approach finds equilibrium by checking that all derivatives up to the order of the differential equation are below a threshold. Following the template (defined below) suggested by the OP, here is an example for a damped harmonic oscillator:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

eqns1 = {a''[t] == Pi^2/2500 - (Pi^2*a[t])/2500 - 0.02*a'[t], 
         a[0] == 0., a'[0] == 0};

steps1 = {};    
sol1 = equilibriumNDSolve[eqns1, {a}, {t, 0, 1000}, a, 
                          equilibriumThreshold -> 1*^-5, 
                          equilibriumStepMonitor :> AppendTo[steps1, t]];

end1 = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a /. sol1[[1]]][[1, 2]];
Plot[a[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, end1}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
     Prolog -> {Thin, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 2}}] & /@ steps1[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]}, 
     PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {t, a[t]}]
```

stops early (t=656.59), giving

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The dashed vertical lines show the step monitor times. That is a 2nd order differential equation. The OP's example is a first order differential equation:

```
eqns2 = {Derivative[1][a][t] == -a[t] - 0.2` a[t]^2 + 2.1` b[t], Derivative[1][b][t] == a[t] + 0.1` a[t]^2 - 1.1` b[t], a[0] == 0.5`, b[0] == 0.5`};

steps2 = {};
sol2 = equilibriumNDSolve[eqns2, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1000}, a + b, 
                          equilibriumThreshold -> 1*^-3, 
                          equilibriumStepMonitor :> AppendTo[steps2, t]];
end2 = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a /. sol2[[1]]][[1, 2]];
Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, end2}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
     Prolog -> {Thin, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1100}}] & /@ steps2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {t, Row[{a[t], ", ", b[t]}]}]
```

uses a threshold of 1*^-3, and stops at t=465.234:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the definition of `equilibriumNDSolve[]`:

```
Clear[equilibriumNDSolve];
Options[equilibriumNDSolve] = {equilibriumThreshold :> 1*^-5, equilibriumStepMonitor -> None};
equilibriumNDSolve[eqns_, vars_, {t_, start_, finish_}, equilibriumexpr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{threshold, order},
    threshold = OptionValue[equilibriumThreshold];
    order = Max[Cases[eqns, Derivative[n_][_][_] :> n, Infinity]];
    NDSolve[eqns, vars, {t, start, finish}, Method -> {"EventLocator", 
      "Event" -> And @@ ((Distribute@Abs[Through[
         Distribute[Derivative[#][equilibriumexpr]][t], Plus]] <threshold) & /@    Range[order])}, 
      StepMonitor :> OptionValue[equilibriumStepMonitor]]]
```

The key part is the `"EventLocator"` method of `NDSolve`, as pointed out by Sjoerd and Szabolcs.

The function expects the stopping criterion (`equilibriumexpr`) to involve at most the addition of the NDSolve variables (more complicated expressions do not work as-is). The transformation of `equilibriumexpr` into an `Event` is not clean (i.e., not easy to follow), and may not be robust, but it works for the two cases above.

Comment: Nice solution checking the derivatives and dealing with DE of any order.

Comment: (+1), but one should point out that higher-order equations like the one in this example can be reduced to a system of first-order equations, so that the other methods based on systems of first-order equation also apply to this example and have more generality.

Comment: @Jens feel free to edit my answer to address your comment.

Comment: On Sjoerd's answer you mention that your solution "doesn't need an extra package as you can extract the domain... but I can't find where this functionality is documented."  I'm alright with undocumented functionality!  Would you be so kind as to elaborate on this?  Great solution.

Comment: @Ghersic. Can't you just take `Head[ifunc][[1,2]]` where `ifunc` is the `InterpolatingFunction`?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`EventLocator` method of NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html).

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

eqns = {Derivative[1][a][t] == -a[t] - 0.2` a[t]^2 + 2.1` b[t], 
   Derivative[1][b][t] == a[t] + 0.1` a[t]^2 - 1.1` b[t], 
   a[0] == 0.5`, b[0] == 0.5`};

sol = First@
  NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
   Method -> {"EventLocator", 
     "Event" -> Abs[a'[t]] + Abs[b'[t]] > 0.1}]

end = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[a /. sol][[1, 2]]

Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, end}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used the condition `Abs[a'[t]] + Abs[b'[t]] <= 0.1` to stop the integration.

I am not really familiar with `EventLocator`, so I had to check the documentation, and I might have missed something. There might be cleaner ways to do this.

---

At least in version 8, you can also get the interpolating function's domain using `a["Domain"] /. sol`, but I don't know where this is documented.  I'd appreciate a pointer!

Comment: Bummer. I was working along the same lines. BTW Shouldn't the  Abs[a'[t]] + Abs[b'[t]] > 0.1 in your code be <0.1?

Comment: @Sjoerd Interesting point about the inequality.  First I assumed the event must be a numerical quantity, and that the integration would stop when it crosses zero.  So I actually used `Boole[Abs[a'[t]] + Abs[b'[t]] > 0.1]`.  The I removed the `Boole` and noted that it still works, so I posted this version.  The interesting thing is that it works no matter if we use `>`, `<` or `==`.  I think it just detects a change in truth value in this case.

Comment: The documentation says "Event functions are expected to be real- or Boolean-valued, so if there is a change, there must be an event in the step interval"

Answer (score 22):

My variant of Szabolcs code. It doesn't need an extra package:

```
sol = First[
   NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1000}, Method -> {"EventLocator",
       "Event" -> Abs[a'[t]] +Abs[b'[t]] < 10^-5, 
      "EventAction" :> Throw[end = t, "StopIntegration"]}]];

Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, end}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see it makes use of the "EventAction" option which stops the integration and also returns the end point in the end variable.

Comment: Mine doesn't need an extra package either as you can extract the domain apparently by passing "Domain" to the interpolating function.  But I can't find where this functionality is documented, so I didn't feel so secure about it.

Answer (score 8):

You can explicitly find the stable values, then integrate the ODE system until they are nearly attained.

```
sys = {Derivative[1][a][t] == -a[t] - 0.2` a[t]^2 + 2.1` b[t], 
   Derivative[1][b][t] == a[t] + 0.1` a[t]^2 - 1.1` b[t]};
inits = {a[0] == 0.5`, b[0] == 0.5`};
vars = {a[t], b[t]};

stopvals = 
 vars /. NSolve[Join[sys, Thread[D[vars, t] == 0]], 
   Join[vars, D[vars, t]]]

Out[279]= {{100., 1000.}, {0., 0.}}

thresh = .01;

endtime = 
 Reap[soln = 
    First@NDSolve[Join[sys, inits], vars, {t, 0, 10^4}, 
      Method -> {"EventLocator", 
        "Event" -> 
         Abs[a[t] - stopvals[[1, 1]]] + 
           Abs[b[t] - stopvals[[1, 2]]] <= thresh, 
        "EventAction" :> Sow[t]}]][[2, 1, 1]]


Out[301]= 525.745

Plot[Evaluate[vars /. soln], {t, 0, endtime}]
```

[image]

Comment: How come I did not think of this? Though there is the open question: how much extra time is required for running `NSolve`? My calculations show that the `NSolve` and `NDSolve` lines use the same magnitude of time, meaning that this code practically doubles the time of finding equilibrium (so it might be slower for more complicated situations).

Comment: @Istvan Zachar I would expect that NSolve won't be a bottleneck unless the equations are nonlinear in a[t] et al.